# Eliminar un objeto de una lista mediante su atributo id

Tags: java

Como ven tengo una lista que contiene objetos de la clase radioreloj y este objeto tiene un atributo id, ok lo que estoy haciendo es recorrer la lista e imprimir y solicito por teclado que ingrese un numero para eliminar el objeto, se elimina el objeto y nuevamente se recorre la lista y se modifica el id del objeto.

lo que yo busco es poder eliminar el objeto con id 2 y eso lo hago ingresando 2 por teclado y lo remuevo asi `listaRadioReloj.remove(opcion-1);`

entonces me quedaria el objeto con id 1 y 3 pero ahora ya no puedo usar lo mismo que hice antes entonces lo que necesito es ver como puedo eliminar un objeto mediante su id.

esto fue lo ultimo que intente pero la idea no es cambiar su id, la idea es que mantenga su id.

```
 ArrayList<RadioReloj> listaRadioReloj = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Reloj reloj = new Reloj(12,12,52);

    RadioReloj radioreloj1 = new RadioReloj(1,"Azul",1.2,true,reloj);
    RadioReloj radioreloj2 = new RadioReloj(2,"Verde",1.5,true,reloj);
    RadioReloj radioreloj3 = new RadioReloj(3,"Rojo",2.2,true,reloj);

    listaRadioReloj.add(radioreloj1);
    listaRadioReloj.add(radioreloj2);
    listaRadioReloj.add(radioreloj3);

    for(RadioReloj radioRelojj: listaRadioReloj){
        System.out.println(radioRelojj);
    }
    // Eliminar RadioReloj opcion 1
    ///*
    contador = 1;
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Seleccione el ID del RadioReloj a eliminar");
        opcion = input.nextByte();
        listaRadioReloj.remove(opcion-1);
        for(int i=0; i<listaRadioReloj.size(); i++){
            listaRadioReloj.get(i).setID(contador);
            System.out.println(listaRadioReloj.get(i));
            contador++;
        }
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es que no estás eliminando el radioreloj por su id, sino por su posición en la lista.
Deberías recorrer la lista y preguntarle a cada radioreloj cuál es su id, y decidir si deber ser eliminado o actualizado en base a ese id y no por el lugar que ocupa en la lista.

La clase RadioReloj debiera tener un getter getId() que devuelva su id. Usando ese método podés preguntarle al radioReloj cual es su id. Y la pregunta se la harías dentro del for que recorre la lista completa.

*La milla extra*: Como optimización podés hacer que una vez encontrado el radioReloj en cuestión, se corte el loop con un `break`.

Comment: toda la razon tenia que hacer esta condicion if (listaRadioReloj.get(i).getID() == opcion) y me funciono